# How to display all the inputs of an array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have defined an array of object like so:

```
 var person = [{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"}, {firstName:"Arunima", lastName:"Ghosh", age:20, eyeColor:"black"}];
```

Now doing

```
console.log(person); 

returns "[Object,Object]"
```

I want to print the details of the array. How do I do this?

Comment: "Print" in what sense? Just to the console? What is the desired output format? `[Object, Object]` indicates an array containing two objects. In the console you should see a little arrow to the left of that, and if you click it it will expand the array to show more details of the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already pointed out, you can use `JSON.stringify`. However, your JSON shows Objects which are collapsable, so you have the information there. If you want to prettify your output further, you may try [pretty-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-js) or [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:
console.table(person);

This would print the object in tabular format which would be easy on the eyes.
Result would look like this:
[image]

This is a lesser known feature compared to console.log but it is very handy at times.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know you can do that! Though it's pretty buggy on Chrome (mac) and causing all sorts of rendering issues.

Answer (score 3):

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(person));
```

That's one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var person = [{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"}, {firstName:"Arunima", lastName:"Ghosh", age:20, eyeColor:"black"}] ;

console.log(JSON.stringify(person));

//if you want to parse
for (var i = 0; i < person.length; i++) {
    var object = person[i];
    for (var property in object) {
        alert('item ' + i + ': ' + property + '=' + object[property]);
    }
    }
```

IS this what you want? If not please elaborate.

Comment: Hi Sachin,

Can you please explain how the following part is working? :

    for (var property in object) {
            alert('item ' + i + ': ' + property + '=' + object[property]);
1. How is property becoming the object property (firstname) and object[property] becoming it's value (John)?

Comment: there is a foreach applied for the jsonArray `person` which is breaking it into objects. And code iterates through each object. Secondaly, the code is picking up each property of object inside alert one by one.

Comment: Thanks so much. but, two questions
1. how is "property" becoming (say) first name and "object[property]" it's value (say) John?
from what I understand property is a declared variable and not a reserved word correct?
2. How will this code work with foreach?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const something = JSON.stringify([
    {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"}, 
    {firstName:"Arunima", lastName:"Ghosh", age:20, eyeColor:"black"}
  ], null, " ");

document.querySelector("#result").textContent = something;

// or in the console
console.log(something);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
var person = [{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"}, 
{firstName:"Arunima", lastName:"Ghosh", age:20, eyeColor:"black"}];

JSON.stringify(person);
```